# Issues while inflating xml in ANDROID

Tags: android, xml, inflate

I have a button in the inflated xml and I wanted to take it's xml id .Please help me with some stuff........ 
I have inflated something like this.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
```

//create a view to inflate the layout_item (the xml with the textView created before)

```
view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflate, mainLayout,false);
```

//add the view to the main layout

```
mainLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: what is your problem? Do you need to get a layout or view from the inflated layout? you can use view.findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId);

Comment: @kavya what is ur question?

Comment: Where is the question..?

Comment: @kavya you want to any childview to the relative layout!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id. relative);
View childLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
mainLayout.addView(childLayout);
```